# Using php exec function in Ubuntu does not work

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

I have the following issue I am using Ubuntu and I am using a simple libreOffice conversion command

```
$command_conversion = 'libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/stilian/Desktop /home/stilian/Desktop/sample.doc';

exec($command_conversion. $output);
```

The command is working fine in the terminal but not when I open the webpage to execute the command. I also double checked for errors in the command there are none. also the variable $output is an empty array. Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Comment: What happens when you execute the command through webpage? Does it give any errors? Also, can you check the returned value of exec command using the last optional parameter?

Comment: is `libreoffice` in the PATH of the webserver user (www-data usually)

Comment: The variable is empty and it gives no errors whatsoever. @apokryfos What do you mean I am new to Ubuntu if you can be more specific.

Comment: Check `$_SERVER["PATH"]` and make sure the path to `libreoffice` binary is in the path variable e.g. do `which libreoffice` and if e.g. the result is `/usr/local/bin/libreoffice` you need to check if `/usr/local/bin` is in `$_SERVER["PATH"]`

Comment: The path to the libreoffice is "usr/lib/libreoffice/program" and it is not in the variable. Should I add it somehow ?

Comment: Actually I did in the terminal "which libreoffice" and folder is usr/bin which is present in the $_SERVER["PATH"].

Comment: Can you try changing user to www-data then execute the same libreoffice command? You can change the current user to www-data using ```$ sudo su -s /bin/bash www-data```

Comment: it prompts me for password in the terminal how do I do that through php ?

Comment: Do not do it with the php just use the console. The password it asks is the password of current user.

Comment: I did it, it does not work, it cannot convert it with that user

Comment: Does it show any errors/warnings?

Comment: it does the first time when I convert it with my user (admin  I guess) it shows 2 errors but it converts the file and everything is fine there are the errors:

     "javaldx: Could not a find a java runtime Environment!
     Warning: failed to read path from javaldx"

When I use user www-data the following occurs:

     "[Java Framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument 
     (elements.cxx)
     javaldx failed!
     Warning Failed to read path from javaldx"

Answer (score 1):

Change dot by comma

```
$command_conversion = 'libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/stilian/Desktop /home/stilian/Desktop/sample.doc';

exec($command_conversion, $output);
```

Comment: It was changed when I was writing it I made the mistake, sorry about that.